# Create age stratified table for age range in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `tt`. I want to create an age-stratified table for age greater than 0 and less than 65, 70 and 75. This is the dta from Alzheimer project and there are some values such as -9 and 888 in age of onset, age at last vist, and age at death columns.  -9 and 888 indicate unknown age.

So, I wrote this code to do the stratified analysis, but I am not sure how to set range for age 0 and above and less than <65, <70 and <75. My code right now also counts values such as -9. Is there a way to prevent that?

```
 tt %>% 
      group_by(STATUS, ETHNICITY) %>%
      summarise('<65' = sum(as.numeric(as.character(AGE_AT_ONSET)) < 65, 
                            na.rm = TRUE), 
                '<70'= sum(as.numeric(as.character(AGE_AT_ONSET)) < 70, 
                           na.rm = TRUE),
                '<75'= sum(as.numeric(as.character(AGE_AT_ONSET)) < 75, 
                           na.rm = TRUE))


    tt <- structure(list(IID = structure(c(`5068` = 80L, `15562` = 58L, 
`8939` = 52L, `17602` = 34L, `3173` = 40L, `12591` = 30L, `17391` = 97L, 
`8241` = 93L, `9746` = 10L, `9673` = 7L, `16594` = 29L, `16911` = 60L, 
`4796` = 18L, `6598` = 12L, `11462` = 26L, `16425` = 17L, `12698` = 37L, 
`17118` = 81L, `1501` = 76L, `13294` = 92L, `8072` = 84L, `11642` = 46L, 
`4164` = 85L, `9035` = 62L, `16691` = 35L, `16002` = 86L, `3915` = 21L, 
`7409` = 54L, `9759` = 11L, `6130` = 6L, `15153` = 23L, `13539` = 100L, 
`13262` = 87L, `742` = 28L, `17592` = 33L, `16812` = 53L, `213` = 66L, 
`11963` = 77L, `12093` = 89L, `11910` = 68L, `15813` = 73L, `1104` = 51L, 
`1966` = 95L, `5589` = 61L, `8860` = 41L, `482` = 16L, `3967` = 55L, 
`5869` = 1L, `12435` = 20L, `11675` = 50L, `16701` = 36L, `5893` = 2L, 
`16880` = 57L, `13290` = 90L, `1097` = 49L, `1476` = 71L, `9100` = 67L, 
`6220` = 8L, `15393` = 42L, `16631` = 31L, `9641` = 4L, `13485` = 99L, 
`1028` = 44L, `8200` = 91L, `12190` = 94L, `5581` = 19L, `7266` = 43L, 
`12254` = 98L, `15763` = 69L, `17764` = 79L, `16239` = 96L, `7548` = 59L, 
`12037` = 83L, `7813` = 70L, `12943` = 63L, `17748` = 75L, `12703` = 38L, 
`11964` = 78L, `14018` = 45L, `1769` = 88L, `13713` = 22L, `13100` = 74L, 
`13866` = 32L, `2527` = 25L, `2281` = 15L, `4463` = 39L, `5815` = 14L, 
`14040` = 47L, `16560` = 24L, `12887` = 56L, `11167` = 13L, `6123` = 5L, 
`5668` = 48L, `3036` = 82L, `7622` = 65L, `11470` = 27L, `4770` = 64L, 
`17050` = 72L, `6295` = 9L, `9575` = 3L), .Label = c("08AD09051_NACC295883", 
"08AD10766_NACC977458", "08AD9133", "09AD14006", "09AD14313_NACC904765", 
"09AD14360_NACC785663", "09AD14874", "09AD14943_NACC009736", 
"09AD15417_NACC169039", "09AD15778", "09AD15810", "09AD17022_NACC426380", 
"25795", "NACC026302", "NACC026743", "NACC044624", "NACC062886", 
"NACC083669", "NACC088187", "NACC094571", "NACC107551", "NACC134929", 
"NACC178119", "NACC178349", "NACC183751", "NACC186606", "NACC192719", 
"NACC193548", "NACC209758", "NACC224665", "NACC243923", "NACC246256", 
"NACC261383", "NACC283729", "NACC298544", "NACC305567", "NACC310219", 
"NACC310896", "NACC312856", "NACC336802", "NACC342957", "NACC350799", 
"NACC351234_09AD13080", "NACC355338", "NACC355951", "NACC361682", 
"NACC369873", "NACC397276", "NACC402765", "NACC403144", "NACC407162", 
"NACC412031", "NACC413408", "NACC422516_08AD10849", "NACC436908", 
"NACC465387", "NACC472288", "NACC479723", "NACC485644_08AD8204", 
"NACC504120", "NACC508353", "NACC509594", "NACC510498", "NACC519864", 
"NACC521718_08AD9198", "NACC559675", "NACC585997", "NACC605438", 
"NACC612578", "NACC619036_09AD14621", "NACC621261", "NACC634809", 
"NACC635885", "NACC639654", "NACC640099", "NACC642393", "NACC660918", 
"NACC660981", "NACC684037", "NACC690933", "NACC695603", "NACC703758", 
"NACC740374", "NACC744168_08AD7716", "NACC766835", "NACC769330", 
"NACC775129", "NACC792439", "NACC796641", "NACC805995", "NACC806269_09AD13056", 
"NACC809589", "NACC824113_08AD9038", "NACC884140", "NACC916661", 
"NACC921664", "NACC926195", "NACC929277", "NACC959601", "NACC992086"
), class = "factor"), AGE_AT_ONSET = structure(c(`5068` = 4L, 
`15562` = 16L, `8939` = 24L, `17602` = NA, `3173` = 24L, `12591` = NA, 
`17391` = 15L, `8241` = 13L, `9746` = 18L, `9673` = NA, `16594` = 20L, 
`16911` = NA, `4796` = NA, `6598` = NA, `11462` = 20L, `16425` = NA, 
`12698` = NA, `17118` = NA, `1501` = 5L, `13294` = NA, `8072` = 11L, 
`11642` = NA, `4164` = 25L, `9035` = NA, `16691` = NA, `16002` = NA, 
`3915` = NA, `7409` = 21L, `9759` = 14L, `6130` = NA, `15153` = NA, 
`13539` = NA, `13262` = NA, `742` = 26L, `17592` = 28L, `16812` = 9L, 
`213` = 14L, `11963` = NA, `12093` = NA, `11910` = NA, `15813` = 10L, 
`1104` = NA, `1966` = NA, `5589` = 16L, `8860` = 8L, `482` = NA, 
`3967` = 7L, `5869` = NA, `12435` = NA, `11675` = NA, `16701` = 19L, 
`5893` = NA, `16880` = 22L, `13290` = NA, `1097` = NA, `1476` = 7L, 
`9100` = 22L, `6220` = NA, `15393` = NA, `16631` = NA, `9641` = NA, 
`13485` = NA, `1028` = NA, `8200` = NA, `12190` = NA, `5581` = NA, 
`7266` = 17L, `12254` = 17L, `15763` = NA, `17764` = 6L, `16239` = NA, 
`7548` = 14L, `12037` = 27L, `7813` = 26L, `12943` = NA, `17748` = NA, 
`12703` = NA, `11964` = 20L, `14018` = 23L, `1769` = 25L, `13713` = NA, 
`13100` = NA, `13866` = NA, `2527` = 12L, `2281` = NA, `4463` = 1L, 
`5815` = 3L, `14040` = NA, `16560` = NA, `12887` = 14L, `11167` = NA, 
`6123` = NA, `5668` = 5L, `3036` = 2L, `7622` = 7L, `11470` = NA, 
`4770` = 17L, `17050` = 15L, `6295` = NA, `9575` = 19L), .Label = c("44", 
"52", "56", "58", "60", "61", "888", "64", "65", "66", "67", "69", 
"70", "71", "72", "-9", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", 
"81", "82", "83", "88", "90"), class = "factor"), AGE_LAST_VISIT = structure(c(`5068` = 8L, 
`15562` = 18L, `8939` = 24L, `17602` = 16L, `3173` = 21L, `12591` = NA, 
`17391` = 17L, `8241` = NA, `9746` = NA, `9673` = NA, `16594` = 25L, 
`16911` = 4L, `4796` = 5L, `6598` = NA, `11462` = 21L, `16425` = 10L, 
`12698` = 25L, `17118` = 12L, `1501` = 7L, `13294` = 9L, `8072` = NA, 
`11642` = NA, `4164` = 21L, `9035` = 21L, `16691` = 3L, `16002` = 14L, 
`3915` = 13L, `7409` = NA, `9759` = NA, `6130` = 25L, `15153` = 22L, 
`13539` = NA, `13262` = 24L, `742` = 26L, `17592` = 30L, `16812` = 9L, 
`213` = 11L, `11963` = NA, `12093` = NA, `11910` = NA, `15813` = 10L, 
`1104` = 24L, `1966` = 14L, `5589` = 18L, `8860` = 23L, `482` = 15L, 
`3967` = 7L, `5869` = NA, `12435` = 6L, `11675` = NA, `16701` = 25L, 
`5893` = NA, `16880` = 20L, `13290` = NA, `1097` = 8L, `1476` = 5L, 
`9100` = 28L, `6220` = 21L, `15393` = 17L, `16631` = 9L, `9641` = 24L, 
`13485` = NA, `1028` = 7L, `8200` = NA, `12190` = 8L, `5581` = 15L, 
`7266` = NA, `12254` = 19L, `15763` = 7L, `17764` = 6L, `16239` = 11L, 
`7548` = NA, `12037` = 29L, `7813` = NA, `12943` = NA, `17748` = 23L, 
`12703` = 27L, `11964` = 23L, `14018` = 26L, `1769` = 24L, `13713` = 13L, 
`13100` = 20L, `13866` = NA, `2527` = 13L, `2281` = 21L, `4463` = 4L, 
`5815` = 3L, `14040` = 2L, `16560` = 14L, `12887` = 24L, `11167` = NA, 
`6123` = NA, `5668` = 12L, `3036` = 1L, `7622` = NA, `11470` = 18L, 
`4770` = 18L, `17050` = 18L, `6295` = NA, `9575` = NA), .Label = c("59", 
"60", "61", "62", "64", "65", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", 
"-9", "74", "-9", "76", "77", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", 
"85", "86", "89", "91", "92", "93", "94"), class = "factor"), 
    AGE_AT_DEATH = structure(c(`5068` = 2L, `15562` = NA, `8939` = NA, 
    `17602` = NA, `3173` = NA, `12591` = NA, `17391` = NA, `8241` = 10L, 
    `9746` = 9L, `9673` = NA, `16594` = NA, `16911` = NA, `4796` = NA, 
    `6598` = NA, `11462` = NA, `16425` = NA, `12698` = NA, `17118` = NA, 
    `1501` = NA, `13294` = NA, `8072` = 6L, `11642` = NA, `4164` = NA, 
    `9035` = NA, `16691` = NA, `16002` = NA, `3915` = NA, `7409` = 16L, 
    `9759` = 8L, `6130` = NA, `15153` = NA, `13539` = NA, `13262` = NA, 
    `742` = 14L, `17592` = NA, `16812` = NA, `213` = NA, `11963` = NA, 
    `12093` = NA, `11910` = NA, `15813` = NA, `1104` = NA, `1966` = NA, 
    `5589` = NA, `8860` = NA, `482` = NA, `3967` = NA, `5869` = NA, 
    `12435` = NA, `11675` = NA, `16701` = NA, `5893` = 16L, `16880` = NA, 
    `13290` = NA, `1097` = NA, `1476` = 1L, `9100` = NA, `6220` = NA, 
    `15393` = NA, `16631` = NA, `9641` = NA, `13485` = NA, `1028` = NA, 
    `8200` = NA, `12190` = NA, `5581` = NA, `7266` = 11L, `12254` = NA, 
    `15763` = NA, `17764` = 3L, `16239` = NA, `7548` = 6L, `12037` = 15L, 
    `7813` = 13L, `12943` = NA, `17748` = NA, `12703` = NA, `11964` = NA, 
    `14018` = NA, `1769` = 12L, `13713` = NA, `13100` = NA, `13866` = NA, 
    `2527` = 5L, `2281` = NA, `4463` = NA, `5815` = NA, `14040` = NA, 
    `16560` = NA, `12887` = NA, `11167` = NA, `6123` = NA, `5668` = NA, 
    `3036` = NA, `7622` = 4L, `11470` = NA, `4770` = NA, `17050` = NA, 
    `6295` = NA, `9575` = 7L), .Label = c("66", "70", "71", "73", 
    "74", "75", "77", "79", "82", "83", "85", "86", "88", "90", 
    "93", "94"), class = "factor"), ETHNICITY = structure(c(`5068` = 4L, 
    `15562` = 4L, `8939` = 4L, `17602` = 3L, `3173` = 4L, `12591` = 4L, 
    `17391` = 4L, `8241` = 4L, `9746` = 4L, `9673` = 4L, `16594` = 4L, 
    `16911` = 4L, `4796` = 4L, `6598` = 4L, `11462` = 4L, `16425` = 4L, 
    `12698` = 4L, `17118` = 4L, `1501` = 4L, `13294` = 4L, `8072` = 4L, 
    `11642` = 4L, `4164` = 1L, `9035` = 4L, `16691` = 4L, `16002` = 4L, 
    `3915` = 2L, `7409` = 4L, `9759` = 4L, `6130` = 4L, `15153` = 4L, 
    `13539` = 4L, `13262` = 4L, `742` = 4L, `17592` = 3L, `16812` = 4L, 
    `213` = 1L, `11963` = 4L, `12093` = 4L, `11910` = 4L, `15813` = 4L, 
    `1104` = 4L, `1966` = 4L, `5589` = 1L, `8860` = 4L, `482` = 4L, 
    `3967` = 4L, `5869` = 4L, `12435` = 4L, `11675` = 4L, `16701` = 4L, 
    `5893` = 4L, `16880` = 4L, `13290` = 4L, `1097` = 4L, `1476` = 4L, 
    `9100` = 4L, `6220` = 4L, `15393` = 4L, `16631` = 4L, `9641` = 4L, 
    `13485` = 4L, `1028` = 4L, `8200` = 4L, `12190` = 4L, `5581` = 4L, 
    `7266` = 4L, `12254` = 4L, `15763` = 4L, `17764` = 3L, `16239` = 4L, 
    `7548` = 4L, `12037` = 4L, `7813` = 4L, `12943` = 4L, `17748` = 3L, 
    `12703` = 4L, `11964` = 4L, `14018` = 4L, `1769` = 4L, `13713` = 4L, 
    `13100` = 4L, `13866` = 4L, `2527` = 4L, `2281` = 2L, `4463` = 4L, 
    `5815` = 4L, `14040` = 4L, `16560` = 4L, `12887` = 4L, `11167` = 4L, 
    `6123` = 4L, `5668` = 4L, `3036` = 4L, `7622` = 4L, `11470` = 4L, 
    `4770` = 2L, `17050` = 4L, `6295` = 4L, `9575` = 4L), .Label = c("AA", 
    "Asian", "Hispanic", "NHW"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the values that you don't want to count to `NA` :

```
library(dplyr)

tt %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('AGE'), 
        ~as.numeric(as.character(replace(., . %in% c(-9, 888), NA))))) %>%
  group_by(ETHNICITY) %>%
  summarise('<65' = sum(AGE_AT_ONSET < 65, na.rm = TRUE), 
            '<70'= sum(AGE_AT_ONSET< 70, na.rm = TRUE),
            '<75'= sum(AGE_AT_ONSET < 75, na.rm = TRUE))

#  ETHNICITY `<65` `<70` `<75`
#  <fct>     <int> <int> <int>
#1 AA            0     0     1
#2 Asian         0     0     1
#3 Hispanic      1     1     1
#4 NHW           7    11    19
```